# How do I actually use Image.capInsets in React Native?

Tags: image, parsing, react-native

The RN documentation says this: [image: screenie]

But I really don't understand what `capInsets {top: number, left: number, bottom: number, right: number}` is supposed to mean. Does it expect an object, whose keys are top, left, bottom and right?

Comment: I tried setting `capInsets` to '100 100 100 100' but I got a ` message: Invariant Violation: "capInsets" is not a valid style property.`

Comment: It's not a style, it's a separate prop

Comment: Okay, I realised that after getting the error. Quite right. But how do you actually use the prop?

Comment: There's an example in the UIExplorer:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8b93b99d4a769f86fffc95d65434f2f6a3fd827d/Examples/UIExplorer/ImageCapInsetsExample.js

Comment: Okay thanks!  In fact I realised that I wasn't necessarily looking for `capInsets`... but it's good to understand what that syntax in the documentation means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a usage example in the [UIExplorer demo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8b93b99d4a769f86fffc95d65434f2f6a3fd827d/Examples/UIExplorer/ImageCapInsetsExample.js):

```
<Image
    source={require('image!story-background')}
    style={styles.storyBackground}
    capInsets={{left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15, top: 15}}
    />
```